# シークレットキーの管理はどの様に行うべきか

Tags: firebase, security

### 状況

Laravel8とFirebase Authenticationを用いてWebアプリケーションを作成しました。
以下のサイト様を参考に、`resources/keys/`配下にFirebaseからダウンロードしたjsonファイルを設置し、アプリケーション側で利用しています。

[Laravel6.0 の認証を Firebase のTwitter Oauth認証で行ったメモ](https://qiita.com/hibohiboo/items/11768cb10bf1e7025090)

**.env**

```
FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=secret.json
```

**config/firebase.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'credentials' => [
        'file' => base_path(env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS')),
        'auto_discovery' => true,
    ],
];
```

### 問題

Dockerの開発環境と本番環境でのFirebaseの認証用jsonをどう管理すればよいかがわかりません。
githubを利用しているのですが、流石にここにcommit＆pushしてしまうのはどうかと思いますし、仮にpushしてしまうと本番とDockerの認証用jsonが一緒になってしまいます。

環境ごとに認証用jsonを切り分けてかつ、管理する方法はありますでしょうか？
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

認証情報等を含む GitHub に push すべきではないファイルは、`.gitignore` ファイルを使って無視リストに登録しておくことをお勧めします。

[ファイルを無視する - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/ja/github/getting-started-with-github/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files)

また、環境毎に設定を切り替えて管理する方法としては、`.env.production` や `.env.development` のように個別のファイルに分けて記述する方法があるようです。

(こちらは Ruby での例なのでそのまま当てはまるかは分かりませんが、"dotenv" としての基本的な考え方は応用できそうです)

[What other .env* files can I use? | Ruby dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#what-other-env-files-can-i-use)

以下は少し古いかもしれませんが、Laravel で日本語での解説例になります。

[[Laravel 5.5] 読み込む.envファイルを環境ごとに切り替える](https://qiita.com/mmmmmmanta/items/b992c7d8cd69343b6626)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。.envとはまた別なのですが、例えば.env.productionなどはgit管理しない（コミット＆プッシュしない）と思います。こちらの管理はどうされているのでしょうか？Google Driveなどで共有したりしているのでしょうか？